# What would the answer be?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Both numbers are above $8,$
their HCF is $8$ and
their LCM is $80.$
Find the two possible numbers.
I'm very stuck on this question and was wondering if there was an easy way to answer it

Comment: Think about two positive integers with highest common factor $1$ and lowest common multiple $10$.  Then change them to fit your question

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).